# Use different search in "search box" that in "search bar" in Firefox

Tags: firefox

Before the "search box" doesn't linked to "search bar". Then I can have a different searchs in each.

I want to be able to configure Firefox to have different searchs "search box" and "search bar".

Answer (score 0):

You're quite late to the party. Mozilla removed the [keyword.url](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyword.url) about:config entry way back in Firefox 23.

According to [this article](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/07/31/mozilla-removes-keyword-url-from-firefox-23/) written at that time, the [Keyword Search add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keyword-search/?src=search) allows you to do what you want. The recent user comments show that it still works as of Firefox 38.0.1.